Difference in the CCA security bound of KYBER KEM in IEEE S&P Version and NIST Submission
I was going through the KYBER CCA security bounds. I noticed one intriguing discrepancy in the CCA bound mentioned in IEEE EuroS&P version (https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) and KYBER NIST submission (https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf).
In particular, KYBER IEEE EuroS&P version states that following bound.

For any classical adversary $A$ that makes at most $q_{Ro}$ many
queries to random oracle $H$ and $G$, and $q_D$ queries to the
decryption oracle, there exists an adversary $B$ such that
$$ \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER}^{cca}(A)\leq 3 \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER.CPA}^{cpa}(B)+q_{Ro}\delta+\frac{3 q_{Ro}}{2^{256}} $$

Note that CPA bound of KYBER is stated in IEEE version is

For any adversary $A$, there exists an adversary $B$ such that $$
 \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER.CPA'}^{cpa}(A)\leq 2 \text{Adv}_{ k+1, k,\eta}^{mlwe}(B) $$

Therefore, CCA security bound of KYBER IEEE version can be written as

$$ \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER}^{cca}(A)\leq 6 \text{Adv}_{\sf k+1,k,\eta}^{mlwe}(B)+q_{Ro}\delta+\frac{3 q_{Ro}}{2^{256}} $$

On the other hand, NIST version mentions the below mentioned bound.

Suppose $XOF, H$ and $G$ are random oracles. For any classical
adversary $A$ that makes at most $q_{Ro}$ many queries to random
oracles $XOF, H$ and $G$, there exist adversaries $B$ and $C$ of
roughly the same running time as that of $A$ such that
$$ \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER.CCAKEM}^{cca}(A)\leq 2 \text{Adv}_{k+1, k,\eta}^{mlwe}(B)+ \text{Adv}_{\sf PRF}^{prf}(C)+4q_{Ro}\delta $$

Mainly I am not able to understand the this apparent difference in the factor  $6 \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER.CPA}^{mlwe}$ and $ 2 \text{Adv}_{\sf KYBER.CPA}^{mlwe}$
Am I missing something here ?

It might be useful to compare to a reliable bound. The IND-CCA security proof of Kyber has been formally verified here.
The bound is somewhat annoying to fully explain, so see Theorem 6 on page 20 for full details. Of interest to you, the multiplicative constant they get for the MLWE advantage term is actually 8, not 2 or 6. This constant should be reliable, as it is formally verified.

@MarkSchultz-Wu Thanks for the reference paper. But it seems the bound mentioned in that paper is for ML-KEM and ML-KEM has modified many steps of CRYSTAL-Kyber. Is there a reference where cca bound of kyber is verified?
